# KL divergence between sample and true (multivariate normal) distribution

Tags: probability, distance, multivariate-normal-distribution, kullback-leibler

I was wondering, whether there is a possible interpretation of the KL-Divergence between sample and true distribution in  terms of probabilities. E.g. given $P=\mathcal{N}\left(\mu,\Sigma\right)$ and $Q=\mathcal{N}\left(\hat{\mu},\hat{\Sigma}\right)$ we have
\begin{equation}
D_{KL}\left(P||Q\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left[\log\frac{|\hat{\Sigma}|}{|\Sigma|} - d + \text{tr} \{ \hat{\Sigma}^{-1}\Sigma \} + (\hat{\mu} - \mu)^T \hat{\Sigma}^{-1}(\hat{\mu} - \mu)\right]
\end{equation}
My question refers to the fact that the (scaled) Mahalanobis Distance (which is part of the above) 
\begin{equation}
\frac{T(T-N)}{(T-1)N}(\hat{\mu} - \mu)^T \hat{\Sigma}^{-1}(\hat{\mu} - \mu)
\end{equation}
has an $F$-distribution with $(N,T)$ degrees of freedom (where $N=$ dimension, $T=$ sample size) and therefore yields a probabilistic "value" to judge how "far" $\hat{\mu}$ is away from $\mu$.